# Problema em deixar um background img no body{} reponsive

Tags: css

Estou com um problema para deixar um background img no body{} reponsive.
img:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

codigo:

```
body{

    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;   
    color: #000000;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 100%;
    margin: 0; 
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
     background: url(../img/fundo.jpg); 

}
```

alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Troque `background: url(../img/fundo.jpg);` por `background-image: url(../img/fundo.jpg);`. Quando você usa só `background` está usando um atalho para várias propriedades ao mesmo tempo. Isso está sobrescrevendo seu `background-position`, `-size`, `-repeat` e `-attachment` com os valores padrões.

Comment: Vlw mano obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro coloque um tamanho no `html` e `body` para não ter problemas de resize.

Depois o *Browser lê os CSS de Cima para Baixo*, então primeiro você precisa declarar o Background (que é um "atalho" onde vc pode inserir vários atributos em uma só linha), depois os atributos dele.

```
background: url(http://placeskull.com/500/500); 
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
etc...
```

Ou assim

```
background: url(http://placeskull.com/500/500) center no-repeat fixed / 100%;
```

Veja no Snippet

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    color: #000000;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    background: url(http://placeskull.com/500/500); 
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 100%; 
}
```

> OBS: Devido a ordem de leitura do CSS pelo Browser se for usado algum "atalho" de classe como Borde ou Background podem ocorrer problemas. Principalmente se um atributo depender do outro para ser renderizado pelo Browser. Veja abaixo.

Por exemplo esse CSS **não vai dar certo**:

```
border-color: #f00;
border-style: dashed;
border: 2px;
```

Já assim vai funcionar:

```
border: 2px;
border-color: #f00;
border-style: dashed;
```

Comment: fiz e não deu as img continua repetindo, será q pode ser o bootstrap?

Comment: @Felipe Fiz uma edição no snippet executa ele ai que vc vai ver como ficou

Comment: o problema foi a ordem dos background não foi mano? Agr foi tudo certinho.

Comment: @Felipe foi sim! Você primeiro precisa declarar o BackGround, depois os atributos que ele vai ter como `background-repeat:` `background-sizet:` etc, se colocar esses atributos antes o CSS vai ler errado

Comment: vlw bro obrigado!

Comment: Não é um problema de ordem – apesar da mudança de ordem resolver o problema. É que propriedades como `border` e `background` são atalhos para várias outras ao mesmo tempo. Se você só define uma delas (por exemplo, o espessura da borda em `border`), as demais assumem o valor padrão.

Comment: ahh sim, mano e sobre melhorar a qualidade das img tem como? Pq tipo imgs menores ficam com uma qualidade mt lixo.

Comment: Não @Felipe, se a imagem é pequena o browser vai esticar ela e perder qualidade, não tem jeito.

Comment: @bfavaretto deu uma acertada no texto. O que vc falou faz sentido, é por causa do "short hand" apesar da orem resolver também.

Comment: @hugocsl  eu estou com um problema bem chato tudo q está dentro do body mesmo eu criando uma main e dentro da main uma section fica bom o background-attachment: fixed.

Comment: E quando eu tiro background-attachment fixed do bg ele não fica 100% no height.

Comment: @Felipe coloca isso no CSS `html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; }` para resolver o problema da altura. E não use background-attachment a não ser que vc queira o BG fixo durante a rolagem de tela. Qualquer coisa cria outra pergunta que tento te ajudar

Comment: Eu tirei o fixed e fiz isso do width e height, mas agora aparece uma parte do fundo branco.

Comment: E com attachment o fundo fica normal, mas tudo q está dentro do body fica também.

Comment: E a única coisa q eu não estava querendo q ficasse com o attachment é essa parte do header, mas já tentei de tudo .

Comment: @Felipe cria uma nova pergunta, com seu HTML, CSS etc tudo completinho, ai a gente consegue te responder melhor

Comment: opa blz vou te mandar aqui.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/266753/problema-com-body-e-tag-background-attachment-fixed

Comment: @hugocsl  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/266890/algu%C3%A9m-poderia-me-ajudar-com-essa-script  tem como me dar uma força com isso mano? Tou querendo adicionar ao script para mudar a color do <Ul> junto com a cor do bg.